# Как удалить класс при помощи Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Имеется вот такой код html:

```
<tr>
<td class="alt1">
<div class="smallfont" style="font-size: .6em;"> 
<span style="font-size: 1.35em;">17.02.2017 17:56</span> 
</div>
</td> 
<td class="alt1" style="font-size: .9em;">1</td>
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_8200678"> 
<div>
<a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://forums.kuban.ru/f1032/sotrudnik_udalenno-8200678.html" id="thread_title_8200678" class="normal222">Сотрудник удаленно</a>[nikonowaa]
</div> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Надо удалить вот этот код полностью:

```
<td class="alt1" style="font-size: .9em;">1</td>
```

Можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо найти нужный элемент и вызвать метод `remove`.

```
String html = ...;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

doc.select("td[class=alt1]").remove();
```

Comment: Но их же несколько там? То есть там не одна строка с классом alt1

Comment: А как нужный отличить от других? По внутреннему значению, порядку в родителе или по `style="font-size: .9em;"`? Вы ж не говорите какова ваша конкретная задача...

Comment: Задача удалить именно тот код который я написал вначале. Ну я так понял можно добавить .next() так как он идет второй?

Comment: @Сергей, не знаю что за `next()` но можете попробовать `get(1)`